# Buildout and creating virtualenv under different Python versions

Tags: plone, virtualenv, zope, buildout

I am looking options to integrate Python 3 tools / scripts to Plone's buildout.cfg (which targets Python 2.6). How eggs between different buildout recipes are shared? Because namely, running setup.py for Python 3 eggs would cause syntax errors in Python 2 environment.

- Can I specify Python 3 interpreter (in portable manner) for a buildout recipe like zc.recipe.egg
- Will the rest of the buildout happily eat the eggs coming under this recipe using particular Python interpreter, or would it clash with the host environment
- ... or do one have to create a virtualenv inside buildout itself to get Python 3 stuff installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the executable to be used by many recipes, including `zc.recipe.egg`:

```
[python3.3]
executable = /usr/local/bin/python3.3

[py3script]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
python = python3.3
eggs = py3script
```

That should install the `py3script` scripts with python 3.3. The key here is the `python` key, which points to a section that should have a `executable` option, which is a path to the python executable you want to use.

The executable key is then used by the `easy_install` module internal to `zc.buildout` to run the `setup.py` script and install the egg.

Comment: Sadle, executable = must be absolute path? Because it fails silenty if I just put "python3" there on the first egg install. It says check easy_install output above, but there is no output. However, copy-pasting the command it tries to run runs the command perfectly.

Comment: Even more sadly, it tries to use Distribute py2.6 egg to run easy_install and this naturally fails on Python 3: /opt/local/bin/python3 "-c" "from setuptools.command.easy_install import main; main()" "-mUNxd" "/fast/xxx/../buildout-cache/eggs/tmpkd0548" "-v" "/fast/buildout-cache/downloads/dist/plac-0.9.1.tar.gz"
path=/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg

Comment: File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
    except ValueError, e: